# `tslearn` library and `Learning Shapelets fit`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, time-series

I have a problem with `tslearn` library function `fit`.
I do not know what is its meaning and more importantly I cannot access it in any way. I apologize for a snippet, but please see the last 3 lines of the code (right above the warning).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning, that in feature versions a `default` parameter will change. Your current code is running correctly as expected. Just make sure, that if you update the package you are aware of the warnings. Followed by the [docs](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/shapelets/tslearn.shapelets.LearningShapelets.html):

```
class tslearn.shapelets.LearningShapelets(n_shapelets_per_size=None, max_iter=10000, batch_size=256, verbose=0, optimizer='sgd', weight_regularizer=0.0, shapelet_length=0.15, total_lengths=3, max_size=None, scale=False, random_state=None)
```

scale is currently False und probalby will change to True:

> scale: bool (default: False) Whether input data should be scaled for
> each feature of each time series to lie in the [0-1] interval. Default
> for this parameter is set to False in version 0.4 to ensure backward
> compatibility, but is likely to change in a future version.

Comment: Right, but I wasn't interested in the Warning in red. I was interested how to use and **access** the fit function: `clf.fit(X,y)` cannot be accessed in any way. Please see the line above `print("2222222")`. Running the code just stops after printing 1111111. Also, I do not know what the `fit` function does/changes and where.